# Drupal / jQuery / CSS :: Wrap radio button label in span tag?

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, radio-button

When a radio button is rendered in Drupal, it comes out like:

```
<label class="form-radio" for="sample">
  <input type="radio" name="samp" value="1" />Sample
</label>
```

I've been looking at theming functions (namely, [theme_radios](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_radios/6) and [theme_form_element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form_element/6), but can't figure out how to render the output like

```
<label class="form-radio" for="sample">Sample</label>
<input type="radio" name="samp" value="1" />.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Been combing the forums but haven't found anything to help... I'd even be happy with a jquery solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this after the page is loaded

```
$(function(){
  $("lable.form-radio").each(function(){
     $(this).after($(this).find("input[name=samp]"));
  });
});
```

Comment: apologies... life stole me from my computer for a while... thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you were close—the function theming a *single* radio input is theme_**radio** (not theme_radio**s**, which exists but is different).

To do this, create an override function in your theme's template.php based on [theme_radio](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_radio/6), i.e.

```
<?php
function mytheme_radio($element) {
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-radio'));
  $output = '<input type="radio" ';
  $output .= 'id="' . $element['#id'] . '" ';
  $output .= 'name="' . $element['#name'] . '" ';
  $output .= 'value="' . $element['#return_value'] . '" ';
  $output .= (check_plain($element['#value']) == $element['#return_value']) ? ' checked="checked" ' : ' ';
  $output .= drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
  if (!is_null($element['#title'])) {
    $output = '<label class="option" for="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . $element['#title']  . '</label>' . $output;
  }

  unset($element['#title']);
  return theme('form_element', $element, $output);
}
?>
```

(This works for any of the theme functions found in /includes/form.inc; remember to name the override function after your theme.) Assuming you're using Drupal 6 based on the link you sent.

Comment: @KumbaThought - Don't use jQuery, please! Use the robust Drupal theme override system and avoid having to do things after the page loads. Add my code to your template.php and flush caches. It works!

Answer (score -2):

Another solution for question "How to styling by css input radios inside the label?" For Bootstrap theme its problem))
We can wrap radio label' title in this file:

sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/system/form-element-label.func.php

In lines with `$output` add to `$title` span tag line 70, 80, 89

e.g.   `$output .= '<span>' . $title . '</span>';`

3 days for seeking answer))